# XElement modification, how do I edit the attributes?

Tags: c#, xelement

I have an xelement which is basic html, i want to quickly loop through all the elements that are paragraph tags and set the style attribute or append to it.  I am doing what is below, but it is not changing the master xelement. How can i make this work?

```
    XElement ele = XElement.Parse(body);
    foreach (XElement pot in ele.DescendantsAndSelf("p"))
    {
        if (pot.Attribute("style") != null)
        {
            pot.SetAttributeValue("style", pot.Attribute("style").Value + " margin: 0px;");
        }
        else
        {
            pot.SetAttributeValue("style", "margin: 0px;");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `Value` property - you can retrieve as well as set the attribute value with it. Only adding an attribute is a little more work - you use the `Add()` method and pass an instance of `XAttribute`:

```
if (pot.Attribute("style") != null)
{
    pot.Attribute("style").Value = pot.Attribute("style").Value + " margin: 0px;";
}
else 
{
    pot.Add(new XAttribute("style", "margin: 0px;"));
}
```

It looks though like you are *actually* editing HTML (I might be mistaken though) - in that case be aware that most HTML that works just fine in a browser is **not** valid XML - you should use a parser for HTML in that case, e.g. [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) which will do a much better job at this.